# Do volatile (time-bound) variables exist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**I would like to use a variable which, some time after it was last modified, is discarded (or nullified). Does such a thing exist?**

My usage scenario is the following: a websocket server will be pushing updates to a Vue.js `vm` (a variable, basically) which will trigger a change in the DOM. I would like this change to be reversed (the updated element hidden) some time after the last modification.

The planned implementation gravitates around a [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) which will update a flag on the change of the `vm` variable above, checked periodically via `setInterval` which will in turn modify the `vm` to trigger the hiding once the flag reaches a certain time.

While doable, it does not sound very clever to me.

If there was a way to "fade out" a variable to `null`, it would be straightforward to trigger the DOM element visibility status.

Is there such a mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I would do this is to use a `timeout` which sets your show flag to `false` after a given interval. The simplest solution would be to declare your timer in `data` so it can be cleared and restarted if a new update is received, which you can place inside your watcher:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  watch: {
    myVar() {
      // Make sure we are showing the new value
      this.show = true;

      // Clear the timer because myVar has been updated
      clearTimeout(this.timer);

      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = false;
      }, 2000); // Now start the timer again
    }
  },
  data: {
    show: false,
    myVar: "",
    timer: ""
  }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4jjey2t/